# Microsoft Office - Transparent .eps files have a white background

Tags: microsoft-office, vector-graphics, microsoft-publisher, eps

I am helping a friend design a poster using Microsoft Publisher. I have made him an `.eps` logo which has a transparent background on it. Upon importing this file into Publisher, the background becomes white. How can I make the background transparent?

Answer (score 2):

In Publisher 2007, select the image and then click on the *Set Transparency Color* tool in the Picture toolbar. Now you can select the background colour to be removed.

In Publisher 2010, select the image and then click the Format tab in the Picture Tools section. Click on *Recolor* and then select *Set Transparent Color*.  Now you can select the background colour to be removed.

Comment: That method only works for raster format files; I am using a vector format.